# Do we have retry configuration for Spark-SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-submit, retry-logic

Do we have retry configuration for Spark-SQL?

We have 'spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts' for spark-submit. Do we have similar conf for spark-sql?

Comment: spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts is max# of AM attempts before failing entire spark app submitted. you asking about task level retries with-in ? if so 'spark.task.maxFailures' makes number of retry as '4' (default) before giving up.

Comment: @Karthick I will try and let you. thanks.